# SQL query to keep track of new orders or balance changes in old orders without dates

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, batch-processing

I have a table with records similar to the following

| order_id | order_balance |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | 400 |
| 35 | 200 |
| 36 | 100 |

Once an order_id is inserted i.e. order_id = 34. A new record is not inserted(not an append) when the order_balance changes, the balance itself is updated in the same record. So say the balance for order_id=34 changes tomorrow to 300. When you look at the table tomorrow.

the record for order_id = 34 will look like:

| order_id | order_balance |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | 300 |

So I want to build a table that keeps track of the order_ids and the order_balances that are either newly inserted, or have had the balance change in the last day(or time period, could be hours,days,minutes,etc). I am using pyspark with spark sql.

My first thought is to have a table that keeps track of the balances from yesterday and then compare them with the balances today. However this would be two separate runs of the spark job and would require me to have the table persist between job runs in spark. Is this even possible?

Comment: SQL Server <> SQLite - please correct your tags.

Comment: Also note the table formatting code.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments, I have corrected my tags and added my initial thought process for how to proceed. I have not accepted an answer yet because my problem has slightly changed and I have not found one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a TRIGGER ON  AFTER INSERT/UPDATE? It would then insert or update the new "control_table" according to the rules you want.

Or, if I understood it correctly, you could have a VIEW like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_changed_orders_last_day AS
SELECT 
    order_id, 
    order_balance, 
    order_updated_date
FROM orders
WHERE order_updated_date IS NULL 
   OR order_updated_date >= sysdate()-1;
```

Comment: What if I didnt have the order date, I only have order_id and balances in the table. When a change in balance occurs the old balance gets overwritten in the same record. How would I keep track of the order_ids with balance changes in this scenario?

Comment: You would have to create a new table for control and use a TRIGGER. Below an example for ORACLE. The syntax can vary depending on the database:

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON original_table FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   -- Insert record into control table
   INSERT INTO control_table
   ( order_id,
     old_order_balance,
     new_order_balance,
     date )
   VALUES
   ( :new.order_id,
     :old.order_balance,    -- old value for order balance
     :new.order_balance,  -- new value for order balance
     sysdate()                   -- timestamp
 );
END;

Answer (score 0):

You want to track changes... convert the table into a [System-Versioned Temporal Table.](https://www.sqlshack.com/track-history-data-changes-using-sql-server-2016-system-versioned-temporal-tables/)

Now SQL Server will track every change made to that table by creating a log table for it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new table for control and use a TRIGGER. Below an example for ORACLE. The syntax can vary depending on the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON original_table
   FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   -- Insert record into control table
   INSERT INTO control_table
   ( order_id,
     old_order_balance,
     new_order_balance,
     date )
   VALUES
   ( :new.order_id,
     :old.order_balance,  --gets the old value for order balance
     :new.order_balance,  --gets the new value for order balance
     sysdate()            --gets the timestamp when it occurred
    );
END;
```